# jquery removeClass is not picking up CSS after second or third click.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making an online calendar for my website and want to change the background of the chosen day useing jquery's removeClass and addClass functions. The script works fine on the first click the old day's background is moved to the default color and the clicked day (td) is highlighted.  However, subsequent clicks retain their highlighted color, meaning I have multiple chosen days.

I have tried a range of solutions included .on() live() and various if functions from other posts.

```
$('#calendarGrid td').on("click", function() {  
    $('#calendarGrid td').removeClass('today');         
    $(this).addClass('today');
});
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
#calendarGrid .wEnd{background: #DDD;}
#calendarGrid .wDay{background: #EEE;}
#calendarGrid .today{background: #99BBEE;}
```

and without putting up my whole table here is the HTML

```
<table id="calendarGrid">
    <tr>
        <td name='2012-04-07' class='wEnd today' id='a6'>7</td>
        <td name='2012-04-08' class='wEnd' id='b0'>8</td>
        <td name='2012-04-09' class='wDay' id='b1'>9</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Strangely enough, when I have more javascript that behaves as if `.today` has been removed despite it picking up the `.today` CSS.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: It's semantics but you might want to reserve `.today` for the actual today on the calendar and use `.active` when they click another date like my example below.

Comment: Thanks Pixelbobby - good advice.

Comment: 1. if you don't need to support IE6, why don't use multiple class? 2. you should use delegation, performance will be better;
3. plus, set up a JSfiddle or jsbin will help a lot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2B5Z/3/) for you.  Everything appears to be working...

**HTML**

```
<table id="calendarGrid" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td name='2012-04-07' class='wEnd today active' id='a6'>7</td>
        <td name='2012-04-08' class='wEnd' id='b0'>8</td>
        <td name='2012-04-09' class='wDay' id='b1'>9</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

**CSS**

```
#calendarGrid td{
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#calendarGrid td.active{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#calendarGrid td').live('click', function(){
       $('#calendarGrid td').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});​
```

​

​

Comment: Hey thanks for this I tried your code and got the same result on my page, but this code worked when I deleted a whole lot of other code off the page.  It seems there is some interaction between a different section of code working on the same selector with a hover event.  I am experimenting with whether this is an event propagation/bubbling issue.

Comment: @Fooksie, Okay, well it must be something else outside of this post.  Feel free to make this as the answer however once you resolve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be correct.Probably some bug in the jquery libs.Try putting the google libs before your script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this advice.  I have to admit I caught this issue last night, having not run across it before .

Answer (score -1):

You should try using `toggleClass` like this:

```
$("#calendarGrid td").on('click', function(){
  //$(this) = #calendarGrid td 
    $(this).toggleClass("today");

})
```

Comment: This is not what he wants to do. He's trying to remove the previous element's "today" class and then add the class to the one that was just clicked. Toggling doesn't help.